# Facebook Page Form Lead Distribution on specific app - Business Manager Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-page

I currently manage a Facebook page within a business manager account, associated with two different Facebook apps, each having its own unique webhook URL.

In my setup, I have two distinct campaigns running on the page. For clarity:

Campaign 1: Leads generated from this campaign's form should be directed only to Webhook URL 1.
Campaign 2: Leads generated from this campaign's form should be directed only to Webhook URL 2.
Could you please provide guidance on configuring the system within a business manager account to ensure that form leads from each campaign are accurately directed to their designated webhook URL only and not the other app's webhook url?

When i am trying to create from lead, it is landing on all apps webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update this in Meta Business Suite (https://business.facebook.com/). If you go into your business settings (using the top-left drop-down and clicking the cog icon), you will have a menu option for 'Integrations' and, under that, you will see 'Leads Access'.

See this page for more details: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/618808448980683